# Missing popup when hovering over FFT sink in gnuradio

Tags: wxwidgets, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, gnuradio-companion

I've been watching Michael Ossmann's video guides on SDR on Great Scott Gadgets. In his videos, he hovers over the TTF sink which displays frequencies, power and TTF. If I do this on OS X, I don't get this yellow popup - besides the fact that my TTF sink looks differently.

Is this a setting in gnuradio, or might it be an OS X issue? I'm running gnuradio 3.7.9.1.

Screenshot from the video:
[image: His]

Screenshot from my application:
[image: Mine]

**EDIT:** It appears that installing pyopengl solves this, as WX is falling back to "something". Install it using **pip install pyopengl** and restart gnuradio.

[image: With pyopengl]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think WX fell back to the non-GL version. As Marcus said, this can have a lot of reasons. On OSX, I was, however, only missing python-opengl. Maybe that's also your problem.

I agree that we should switch to QT in the long run, but since there are still several WX projects around, it might be worth having a working installation.

(Couldn't comment since I don't have the required reputation.)

Comment: Oh, wow. Installing pyopengl (pip install pyopengl) changes the image completely. Now I get the same output on OS X, as on Linux. How on earth does one debug this; there is no output in gnuradio about a missing library/falling back to something else.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, and not mine :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree; I wasn't sure of the policy when doing this :). I've changed it. Thanks a lot for your input tho in regards to WX/QT. It makes sense in this case too.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to say what goes wrong with the graphical sink in your case.

However, what I'd propose:

Abandon the WX GUI sinks in favor of the Qt GUI sinks (you will have to change from WX to the QT build option in the option block, and replace your sinks with their QT equivalent). WX is barely still maintained, and might/will be removed from GNU Radio at some point – the QT GUI sinks are just more effective, more portable, and have cool features (try the middle-mouse-button menu!).

In case of a Frequency Plot, things would look something like:
[image: QT GUI frequency sink at work]

Comment: Thank you. I think you might be right in regards to WX being the issue. I replicated what I see in the video on Linux, but on OS X, WX behaves differently (maybe a version thing, not sure).

Comment: @Marcus Müller, is the middle button menu working for you in this qt plot window?

Comment: In the frequency sink? Yes.

Comment: Ahh, I found the reason I was not seeing: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/1305 
we should use the individual sinks instead the old QT GUI Sink.